# Case-Insensitive Sorting with MongoDB Query

Tags: mongodb-query

I am using "MongoDB-3.6.17" and "mongo-java-driver-3.6.4" in my application.
The following are the documents in a MongoDB collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5323850fa89de4a9f691dacf"), "name" : "PQR" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53238511a89de4a9f691dad0"), "name" : "abc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53238515a89de4a9f691dad1"), "name" : "ABC" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53238522a89de4a9f691dad2"), "name" : "xyz" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5323852ea89de4a9f691dad3"), "name" : "XYZ" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5323855ea89de4a9f691dad4"), "name" : "pqr" }
```

Then I have queried with sorting by name:

```
db.collection.find().sort({name:1});
```

And the result is as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53238515a89de4a9f691dad1"), "name" : "ABC" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5323850fa89de4a9f691dacf"), "name" : "PQR" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5323852ea89de4a9f691dad3"), "name" : "XYZ" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53238511a89de4a9f691dad0"), "name" : "abc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5323855ea89de4a9f691dad4"), "name" : "pqr" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53238522a89de4a9f691dad2"), "name" : "xyz" }
```

By default MongoDB is supporting Case-Sensitive sorting.
How do we get the Case-Insensitive sort results with MongoDB query.

Expected Results:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53238515a89de4a9f691dad1"), "name" : "ABC" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53238511a89de4a9f691dad0"), "name" : "abc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5323850fa89de4a9f691dacf"), "name" : "PQR" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5323855ea89de4a9f691dad4"), "name" : "pqr" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5323852ea89de4a9f691dad3"), "name" : "XYZ" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53238522a89de4a9f691dad2"), "name" : "xyz" }
```

Kindly help me some one on case-insensitive sorting in MongoDB.

Thank you.

Regards,
Ram

Comment: does my answer help? Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Using MongoDB Aggregation Framework

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
       "name": 1, 
       "lowerName": { "$toLower": "$name" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "lowerName": 1 } }
])
```

or you can also use `$addFields`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
       "lowerName": { "$toLower": "$name" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "lowerName": 1 } }
])
```

Reference - http://codingpajamas.github.io/2015/05/14/sorting-mongodb-case-insensitive

Comment: the second method is efficient($addFields) because if we are using $project in the pipeline we need to specify which all fields in the document should be returned after executing the query. we need to explicitly mention else it won't return the entire fields in the document. For the other case, the only thing is new field is also getting added to that particular document. which doesn't need more lines of code.